# Check for content type usage - Cannot delete Content Type - SharePoint Online / O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-type

I'm having problem removing / deleting two (2) content types. I managed to delete 14 but there are two left behind. Those two are at the same level as the other ones.

I've deleted:

- all items in lists
- the entire lists (custom)
- fields (site columns)
- reference in lists
- deleted both recycle bins

Still cannot delete the CT. The site collection should now be a clean site collection.

```
Get-SPOContentType | ? { $_.Group.StartsWith("Company")  } | Remove-SPOContentType -Force
```

Is there a good way in SP Online to see the usage of an Content Type?

Comment: These may help you find the content type: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-a-report-on-lists-c2decb62
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-Content-Types-Derived-b48e7f5f

Answer (score 3):

I believe the equivalent of `SPContentTypeUsage` is not available in Client. Hence we can't use PowerShell to scan and report the Usage.

I strongly recommend you check the recycle bin to make sure the reference is holding in there

- Delete from `site recycle bin`
- Delete from `Site Collection` > `Site Settings` > `Site Collection Administration` > `Recycle Bin`
- Delete from `End User Recycle Bin Items`
- Delete from `Deleted From End User Recycle Bin`

Comment: What type of privileges must I have to enter the "End User Recycle Bin Items"? I'm site collection admin .. but then I probably have to be tenant admin to view those. But I managed to delete 14 CT's but only two are left behind.

Comment: By that it means one of the user might have delete a document associated with that content type and it is residing in his/her recycle bin. You can try the other recycle bin's and try deleting the CT again.

Comment: All recycle bins that I have access to are empty. It's a clean site collection now.

Comment: just got this. when we go to the recycle bin there's a text at the bottom of the page "Can't find what you're looking for? Check the Second-stage recycle bin". entered it, deleted "permanently" and then managed to remove the content type